# C# - unhandled exception "System.NullReferenceException"

Tags: c#, exception, error-handling

When trying to find a registry key that does not exist it throws an unhandled exception.

It looks like when checkKey is returned null and it's trying to continue to .GetValue it throws the exception.

```
public static string getDirectory(string path, string subpath)
    {
        if (checkKey(path).GetValue(subpath) != null)
        {
            return checkKey(path).GetValue(subpath).ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I tried if (checkKey(path) != null & checkKey(path).GetValue(subpath) != null) but that didn't resolve the issue.

```
 public static RegistryKey checkKey(string key)
    {
        if (getBaseCurrent64().OpenSubKey(key) != null)
        {
            return getBaseCurrent64().OpenSubKey(key);
        }
        else if (getBaseLocal64().OpenSubKey(key) != null)
        {
            return getBaseLocal64().OpenSubKey(key);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

a try catch would solve this but i feel like I'm doing this wrong.

kind regards,

Comment: Gnerally speaking: do not call a method twice. Call it once, put the return value into a variable and then decide what to do with it.

Comment: `if (checkKey(path) != null && checkKey(path).GetValue(subpath) != null)`, with just one `&` the second part will still be executed, which throws an error. `&&` "short circuits", meaning if the first isn't true, the second won't even be checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a GetValue() when you return null. Try to change your code to

```
public static string getDirectory(string path, string subpath)
{
    RegistryKey key = checkKey(path);
    if (key != null && key.GetValue(subpath) != null)
    {
        return key.GetValue(subpath).ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the logical AND operator (`&&`) instead of the bit-wise AND operator (`&`), change your code to this:

```
if (checkKey(path) != null && checkKey(path).GetValue(subpath) != null)
```